# QtCreator crashes when started over RDP

Tags: qt-creator, remote-desktop

I run qtcreator 3.5.1 on my windows 7 system no problems. Oddly when I try to start it over RDP connection it crashes. If I start it locally everything else seems to work OK over RDP, only starting qtcreator over RDP causes a problem. Really puzzled by this problem. I check the event log and sure enough there is an error, but I have no idea what it might mean.

[image]

One thing I tried was starting as an administrator, on the chance that this might be due to some sort of permissions issue. That didn't help. Another thing that didn't help was starting the executable with a `-noload Welcome` option from the command prompt. I tried this on the off chance that it might be that plugin causing the crash.

I googled possible reasons for this and nothing is giving me any ideas.

Any clues would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with "-noload Welcome". That disables the welcome page which uses OpenGL.

You will also want to avoid QML Designer and the QML profiler wjen you do not have good enough openGL drivers available.